# Why does my GitLab build fail with error: "executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am getting the following error repeatedly on a build

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.8.0 (775dd39d)
  on docker+machine ABwVypz2
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:16
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:6e82c575b16fb92f31c77a6ba88cadffa1720acd6e33526d82814232a82eb780 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:9f9a930bc5ec2e000867a87de844cae04590bafe929340e2fae4cb959cf6bc8f ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "dockerd-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown (docker.go:502:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:6e82c575b16fb92f31c77a6ba88cadffa1720acd6e33526d82814232a82eb780 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:9f9a930bc5ec2e000867a87de844cae04590bafe929340e2fae4cb959cf6bc8f ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "dockerd-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown (docker.go:502:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:6e82c575b16fb92f31c77a6ba88cadffa1720acd6e33526d82814232a82eb780 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:9f9a930bc5ec2e000867a87de844cae04590bafe929340e2fae4cb959cf6bc8f ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "dockerd-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown (docker.go:502:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "dockerd-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown (docker.go:502:0s)
```

Reduced to it's simplest I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yaml`

```yaml
image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - build

.build-image:
    stage: build
    script:
        - docker build ${TAG} ${BUILD_ARGS} -f ${PATH}/${DOCKERFILE} ${PATH}

build-legacy-php:
    extends: .build-image
    parallel:
        matrix:
            - PHP_VERSION: ['5.6', '7.2']
    variables:
        BUILD_ARGS: --build-arg PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
        PATH: php
        DOCKERFILE: Dockerfile.legacy
        TAG: php:$PHP_VERSION-latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching, restarting services, clearing caches and headbanging this turned out to be my stupidity. GitLab was even telling me what the issue was in the error output. I was setting the `PATH` variable which is what the system uses to know where to look for executables so my change caused it to lose the ability to find it's own executables.

Renaming `PATH` to `BUILD_PATH` in the yaml fixed it 100%.

I added this because I couldn't find any reference when I was searching.